# How to filter out only searchable PDFs from amid a myriads PDF files?

Tags: macos, pdf, ocr

I have a folder containing only PDF files from amid which some are searchable PDFs (OCR'ed scanned documents). There are almost 6000 PDF files in the folder and I need to filter out (copy/move to another folder) only the searchable ones.

How can I achieve this, please?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Have you tried examining the metadata associated with one file that is "searchable" and another that isn't? In the terminal app, type `mdls` and then drag both files (together or one by one) into the window and drop the icons. Then press return.

Comment: was?...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just use the finder search, and search for 'the' (or another search term that is guaranteed to be in every searchable pdf). Then just copy those files to another folder.

Just pick a term that doesn't appear in the filenames of the other files.

Comment: Was? Gibt es keine glattere Lösung?

Comment: Ich weiß nicht? Es war eine schnelle Lösung. Funktioniert es?

Comment: Ja, das hat geholfen Vielen Dank!